# ASP.NET MVC 3 use of Canonicalize package and IIS SEO Toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, canonicalization

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, ran the IIS SEO toolkit on it and got "The page contains multiple canonical formats." error caused by the site being accessable with or without a trailing slash.

After searching for advice I found the Canonicalize NuGet Package 
https://github.com/schourode/canonicalize

and am using it as follows in my RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Canonicalize().NoTrailingSlash();               

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "BWS.WebUI.Controllers" });
    }
```

The SEO toolkit then reported "The URL is linked using different casing." so I changed to code to be

```
        routes.Canonicalize().Lowercase().NoTrailingSlash();
```

The SEO toolkit is now reporting "The page contains unnecessary redirects." for all my links because any URLs using uppercase will be redirected to lowercase URLs.

Can anyone advise how best to deal with this? I really want to improve the SEO of my web app.

Answer (score 0):

We have used this plugin / IIS SEO Toolkit to good effect with MVC and have generally had no problems. We also make sure that all our internal site urls are lowercase in the html before we release the website, otherwise in theory you are generating needless redirects without realising - the plugin is just catching them. The plugin should only be used as a safety net to catch the urls you miss.